# Is there a way to create dependent fields in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, field

Is there a way to automatically fill fields based on dependencies? E.g. I have a model with fields answer_type and chart_type, where I want (e.g.) all radio button answer_types to automatically be pie chart_types, and all autofill questions to automatically be bar chart_type.

I don't seem to be able to call functions based on fields within the model, so I'm not sure if this is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

What in particular is preventing you from calling functions based on the model fields? You should be able to define functions within the model, as such:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    answer_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    def chart_type(self):
        if self.answer_type == 'radio':
            return 'pie'
        ...
```

Let me know any problems you run into with that.

Comment: I don't think that works for modifying fields. I.e., I can't do chart_type = self.chart_type. I'm looking for something along the lines of "choices"... I'm not sure of the right way to go about this.

Comment: So are you adamant on having another field for chart types? From what I gathered, you wanted to save all "radio button" answer types as "pie" chart types, without the chart type ever changing. So if the answer type were modified to be a different answer type, would the chart type also have to change? In that case, I feel that the function within the model would suffice. But then again, I don't know your reason for having another field for chart type.